# How to make same background like on bootstrap main page?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, gradient

```css
body>div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Need more here</div>
```

Can someone help with creating the same background as on the bootstrap main page?

I tried with the gradient, but it doesn't work.
I can't get the 4 colors that come together in white in the middle.

Comment: Please update with the HTML and CSS you have tried; added a snippet to assist you here

Comment: FWIW That uses a number of CSS variables that you will need to "sniff out" there

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bs {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.01), rgba(255,255,255,1) 85%), radial-gradient(ellipse at top left, rgba(13,110,253,0.5), transparent 50%),radial-gradient(ellipse at top right, rgba(255,228,132,0.5), transparent 50%),radial-gradient(ellipse at center right, rgba(112.520718,44.062154,249.437846,0.5), transparent 50%),radial-gradient(ellipse at center left, rgba(214,51,132,0.5), transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bs"></div>
```